# iMacro Get Current Item from Select List and Add to It

Tags: imacros

Using iMacros to select multiple items from a list. Need to determine a variable/placeholder to account for the currently selected item and just add to it.

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:frmAddQuestion ATTR=ID:category CONTENT={{PLACEHOLDER HERE}}%162:%252
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:frmAddQuestion ATTR=NAME:SubmitButton1
```

Can't seem to find any way to account for the current selection and just add to it. Your Thoughts?

Comment: I think if I can set a variable equal to the current selection and just pass that back in this should work. Does anyone know how to set a variable equal to the current selection? :)

Comment: I think SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}} is what your looking for, but first you need to find and extract what you call as "current selection"